# Ajax call. Always return error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web-services

Get stacked with ajax call.
I'm allways getting error. I've tried to return from server ArrayList because i have some scheme in some my projects. But the result was same. Json is valid. Staus 200 OK and permanent error.

Here is my client-side code

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "services.aspx/GetHexString",
        data: "{'strGetParamsString':'LYALYA'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        },
        error: AjaxFailed
    });
```

Server-side logic:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetHexString(string strGetParamsString)
    {
        return "HI";
    }
```

Firebug shows 200 OK status. And the result is {"d":"HI"}
http://jsonlint.com/ says that json is valid.

What is wrong?

Comment: The current version of jQuery is 1.6.4 - I suggest you upgrade.

Comment: I know that :) but this version supports ajax and this is not a reason.I've tried to use sevral version with same result.

Comment: Where does `{"d":..}` come from? `Hi` by itself is not valid JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling `{"d":...}` comes from using ASP.NET script services. The runtime automatically wraps the result in the "d" property before returning the JSON object. This is normal.

Answer (score 1):

Tried your code here and it works fine. Have you added text to your error callback to display the error?

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  alert(textStatus);
  alert(errorThrown);
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in erroThrown. It should not be undefined. Try using the code I posted here.

Comment: I've changed the jQuery version to the latest one and its working now but only in firebug debug mode. In live mode i've got an error:
textStatus: error
errorThrown: nothing (null)

Comment: This sounds very odd. If it works with firebug off, you could try using Fiddler to inspect the traffic instead. I also suggest verifying in another browser. If you can post a jsFiddle other users can verify if it is working for them.

Comment: Guys, **asyn: false** option solved my problems even with 1.3.2. Now I have to understand why???
Thanks you all for good advices.

Answer (score 1):

To get more information about you error, add parameters to your error callback function.  From the jQuery docs:

error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)

errorThrown will contain some info.

Comment: added this one alert(jqXHR + "\n" + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown); and get 
textStatus = error, erroThrown = undefined

Comment: maybe the callback function was different in version 1.3.2, errorThrown should be defined in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Add `error_reporting(0);` to the top of your `php` page. With the `json` array that returns if you happen to have an Undefined variable or you have the `error_reporting` on it will mess up the array data. I don't know all the full details on this but it works for me.